# How can i automatically crop an image just taken with react-native-camera

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-camera, react-native-image-picker

I have a feature that captures a bank card, how can I crop the image of the card inside the camera mask. I use react-native-camera to take pictures and use BarcodeMask to create masks.Here is the code:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
<RNCamera
ref={ref => {
this.camera = ref;
}}
style={
this.state.step == 3 ? styles.camview : styles.preview
}
type={this.state.typeCamera}
autoFocus={RNCamera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}
captureAudio={false}
onFacesDetected={res =>
this.checkStatusFace(res.faces[0])
}
onFaceDetectionError={res => {
console.log('loi vao', res);
                          }}
faceDetectionClassifications={
RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Classifications.all
}
/>
<BarcodeMask
width={350}
height={250}
showAnimatedLine={false}
/>
<TouchableOpacity
onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}
style={styles.capture}>
<FontAwesome5 name="camera" size={40} />
</View>
    
    
takePicture = async () => {
console.log('Da chup anh');
if (this.camera) {
const options = {quality: 0.4, base64: true};
const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
this.setState({
uriImage: data.base64,
viewImage: true,
});
console.log(data);
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to use a third-party library to crop image. You can use something like https://github.com/callstack/react-native-image-editor to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: i tried and got an error when importing the library. Do you have any other way?